# Sending a POST request in Postman set to send a certain status sends the default status

Tags: node.js, rest, api, postman

I want that my POST request sends a HTTP 409 in a certain case, so this is the code:

```
res.status(409).send();
```

However, when I tun the request in Postman it shows the result `200 OK`. I put some logs in the code and I'm sure that the above line is hit.

What is wrong?

UPDATE:

Here is the full method:

```
app.post('/orders/:order_id/sync_status', (req, res) => {
    order.findOne({ order_id: req.params.order_id},
        function(err, results) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(`error: ${error}`);
            } else if (!results) {
                res.send(`no order with order_id: ${req.params.order_id}`);
            } else {
                status.findOne({ order_id: req.params.order_id},
                    function(err, result) {
                        if (err) {
                            res.send(`error: ${error}`);
                        } else if (result) {
                            res.status(409).send();
                        } else {
                            const newStatus = new status (req.body);
                            newStatus.save();
                        }
                    });
            }
            res.end();
        });
});
```

and the Postman request:

[image]

Comment: from the code above, nothing is wrong. show the full code together with what is sent via Postman

Comment: @anasceym, I updated the question

Answer (score 1):

The simple reason is because you have `res.end()`

The longer answer is because `res.end()` is executed before this piece

```
status.findOne({order_id: req.params.order_id}, function(err, result) {
  if (err) {
    res.send(`error: ${error}`);
  } else if (result) {
    res.status(409).send();
  } else {
    const newStatus = new status(req.body);
    newStatus.save();
  }
});
```

got executed due to asynchronous call/callback.

Without testing, your final code should look like this

```js
app.post('/orders/:order_id/sync_status', (req, res) => {
  order.findOne({order_id: req.params.order_id}, function(err, results) {
    if (err) {
      return res.send(`error: ${error}`);
    }

    if (!results) {
      return res.send(`no order with order_id: ${req.params.order_id}`);
    }

    status.findOne({order_id: req.params.order_id}, function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        return res.send(`error: ${error}`);
      }

      if (result) {
        return res.status(409).send();
      }

      const newStatus = new status(req.body);
      newStatus.save();
      return res.end();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: so basically you say to add `return` before each `res` call. I did the changes but the result is the same, 200 OK. I also changed the structure, just `if`s, no `if-else`s

Comment: are sure you path fall under the `if` statement there (the line that you return 409)? or do you have any other express route that can possibly make your request go there?

Comment: I'm sure becaue if I add some console.logs in the same block they are printed

Comment: logically, there's no way the express will return 200 if you follow exactly what i suggested above. unless you didnt restart the app after changes

Comment: I solved it. I moved the location of that `res.end()` in the last block

Comment: I tried it like that but didn't work. I also removed the return statements and now it's working.

Comment: yes, i mean, if you look closely my code,  `res.end()` is inside the callback of `deliverooSyncStatus.findOne`